# Example of a smooth function in a manifold whose integration vanishes

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, integration

Let $M$ be a complete Riemannian manifold. Now for a fixed $p\in M$, is there any non-constant smooth function $u:M\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that
$$\int_{B_r}udV=0\ \forall 0\leq r<\infty,$$
where $B_r$ is a ball with center at $p$ and radius $r$. I can not find such an example. I know that in $\mathbb{R}$, the above equation implies that $u$ is zero, but for general case I can not find any example. Please help!

Comment: Why does it hold on $\mathbb{R}$?  What about the function $x\mapsto x$, with $p=0$?

Comment: Ok. I understand. It was my mistake. I have mistakenly taken  $\mathbb{R}^+$.

Comment: It seems to be a sort of mean value problem. There is a huge literature on that for harmonic maps on riemannian manifolds. Try to google "mean value theorem on manifolds" or something like that...

Comment: Huh? This doesn't need anything even a little fancy. If you are nonzero at a point you are nonzero of the same sign in a sufficiently small neighborhood.

Comment: I do not think this is research level. Any odd function will satisfy this property on $\mathbb{R}$, and it not hard to put this example on other manifolds as well.

Comment: If you do not take a fixed $p$, i.e. if for all $p$ the equation is supposed to hold then Mike Miller's answer shows that such functions do not exist

Comment: I did not notice the condition that $p$ is fixed. My apologies.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On the circle $x^2+y^2=1$, the function $x$ has this property for $p=(0,1)$ or $p=(0,-1)$.
On the sphere $|x|^2=1$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, every nonzero linear function restricts to a function with this property, around any point $p$ at which it vanishes. On hyperbolic space, in the ball model, any linear function on the ball has this property about $p$ the origin. Similarly for complex or quaternionic hyperbolic space. 
Suppose that $M$ is a Riemannian manifold and take a point $p$ of $M$. Suppose that $r$ is the injectivity radius of $M$ at $p$. Denote the exponential map as $e \colon B_r(0) \to B_r(p)$ between the balls in $T_p M$ and in $M$. Take the Euclidean volume form $\Omega_p$ on $T_pM$ and the volume form $\Omega_M$ of $M$. Let $F>0$ be the function on $B_r(p)$ so that $e^{-1*}\Omega_p=F\Omega_M$ on $B_r M$. Let $h$ be a linear function on $T_p M$. Let $k$ be a smooth rotationally symmetric function on $T_p M$ with compact support contained in the open ball $B_r(0)$. Then the function $f$ equal to $(e^{-1*}hk)F$ in $B_r(p)$ and equal to zero outside $B_r(p)$ has zero integral on any ball around $p$ in $M$, as the integral is just the Euclidean integral of $hk$ around $0$ in $B_r(0)$.

Comment: So, no completeness needed?

Comment: No completeness needed.